# Inputting variable amount of arguments into function Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a piece of code that I want to pass a variable amount of arguments, where the arguments are the inputs from the command line.

```
con = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
cur = con.cursor()
query = "insert query here"
cur.execute(query, ("first_arg", "potential_second_arg", "potential_third_arg")
```

I tried to put all the arguments into one string but I realised it becomes one argument and not multiple because it's in a single string

```
cur.execute(query, ("first_arg, potential_second_arg, potential_third_arg",)
```

I also don't think I can do

```
cur.execute(query, (for index in range(len(sys.argv)):))
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument of `execute` expects a `tuple` so just pass that

```
cur.execute(query, tuple(sys.argv)) # this passes ALL cli argument, including the program
```

You can slice `sys.argv` to, for example, remove the program name

```py
cur.execute(query, tuple(sys.argv[1:]))
```